# OnKeyPress and keybd_event

Tags: delphi

I want to send the key pressed into a form, over socket, and simulate the same key press on the remote computer. I saw some examples on Internet, but I thought most of them are over complicating the job, so I'm trying to do mine.

Right now, I think the other examples are not over complicating, but maybe the process need to be complicated. What I'm doing so far is:

On the form, I have onkeypress event with code:

```
procedure TForm2.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Ord(Key))); //I put this here just to check the key code I'm
                                   //sending for future reference
  CurrentSocket.SendText('<|KEY|>' + Key);
end;
```

When I press 'a' on this form, I receive the message 97. This code shouldn't be for numpad 1?

Yes, on the receiving side, I simply have:

```
procedure SocketThread.Execute;
var
  ReceivedString: String;
  parserLimit, iAux: integer;
  Key: Char;
begin
  try
    ClientSocket.Active:= true;
    while ClientSocket.Active do
    begin
      if ClientSocket.Socket.ReceiveLength > 0 then
      begin
        ReceivedString:= ClientSocket.Socket.ReceiveText;
        while POS('<|KEY|>', ReceivedString) <> 0 do
        begin
         parserLimit:= POS('<|KEY|>', ReceivedString);
         Key:= ReceivedString[parserLimit + 7];
         Delete(ReceivedString, 1, parserLimit + 7);
         keybd_event(Ord(Key), MapVirtualKey(Ord(Key), 0),0, 0);
         keybd_event(Ord(Key), MapVirtualKey(Ord(Key), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        end;
```

Surprisingly (or not), what I get on this side is the number 1, printed on the screen.

Is possible to make this process as simple as possible, without the need on the form side, using onkeydown event, to check if shift, uppercase, lowercase, etc... The onkeypress gives me the "real" key pressed (upper, lower, symbol), that's why I try to use it.

Comment: OnKeyPress doesn't send virtual key codes. You are looking for OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp.

Comment: I can't simply send the key pressed OnKeyPress, and simulate this press on the receiving side? 

I saw examples using OnKeyDown/OnKeyUp, all of them need to check if shift is pressed to put UpperCase, everything manually. While OnKeyPress already gives me this automatically.

And the examples, in the end, send over the socket, like this:
            `49:
              if (ssShift in Shift) then
                CurrentSocket.SendText('!')
              else
                CurrentSocket.SendText('1'); `

Isn't the same thing that I'm doing?

Comment: `Ord('a')` = 97 on any ASCII table you'd like to check, just like `Ord('A')` is 65. In `OnKeyPress` you're receiving a char (which is why it's declared as `var Key: Char`). You won't know in OnKeyPress whether you received a NumPad key or not. As David said, you need OnKeyDown or OnKeyUp in order to get virtual key codes.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, if I got you correctly, you mean that OnKeyPress I'm getting ASCII table values? While on keybd_event, I'm not able to use ASCII values? Is there any function to use this ASCII values correctly?

Comment: Yes, you're getting ASCII table values, as I said previously. I didn't say anything about using them in keybd_event; I was explaining why you're getting 97 for `a` and why 97 in this case does not represent NUMPAD_1.

Comment: Yes... But on the receiving side, is there anyway to use the ASCII values? And get `a` and not `1`?

Comment: Why make life hard for yourself? Detect the keys, and send them. Don't convert to characters. Perhaps you need to revise what virtual key codes are.

Comment: I will try... Let's see how it goes. If anyone has a good example about how to do it (simple as possible), please post and I accept as answer.

Comment: Why not try yourself? Don't just jump in there and trial and error it. Read about keyboard

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on your receiving side you treat your input as VirtualKey while from sending side you send a Character.

Check this code to see the difference. The purpose of this code is to show the difference between Char value and Key value.

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('KeyPress:'+IntToStr(Ord(Key)));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('KeyUp:'+IntToStr(Key));
end;
```

Any way why don't you simply use OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp events instead and besides sending Key value also send ShiftState.?

If you ever plan on being able to send some shortcut combinations like CTRL+C you will need the Shift state information.